# MLE for uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}[\theta,1]$ and consistency

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have some trouble with the MLE of this distribution.

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ random variables with distribution $\mathcal{U}[\theta, 1]$

$L(\theta) = \prod\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{1-\theta} \ 1_{\{\theta<X_i<1\}}$

$\implies L(\theta) = \cases{ \frac{1}{\left(1-\theta\right)^n}\qquad \text{if } \max{\{X_i\}} < 1\ \ \text{  and  }\ \min{\{X_i\}} > \theta \\
\\0 \qquad \qquad \text{otherwise}}$

Now here is my problem. I cannot use $\min{\{X_i\}}$ mas my estimator because that is a minimum of $L(\theta)$ if $\max{\{X_i\}}<1$.
And so I thought of using $\max{\{X_i\}}$, but when I find the density of this new random variable, I find the MSE (to check consistency) and it doesn't go to 0.

After some calculations I end up with

$\text{MSE} = \frac{-n(2\theta -1)}{(n+2)(1-\theta)^n} + \theta^2\left( 1 + \frac{n\theta^n}{(n+2)(1-\theta)^n} \right)$

What am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\theta$ is the lower endpoint of the uniform distribution from which observations are drawn, it seems natural to estimate $\theta$ using the minimum order statistic $X_{(1)} = \min_i X_i$.  The likelihood is $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid \boldsymbol x) = (1-\theta)^{-n} \mathbb 1(\theta \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le 1).$$  Remember, $\mathcal L$ is fixed with respect to the sample $\boldsymbol x$, and is a function of $\theta$.  You are correct that for positive integers $n$ and $\theta < 1$, the factor $(1-\theta)^{-n}$ is increasing as a function of $\theta$; but this is precisely the point of the indicator function:  $\mathcal L$ only increases up until $\theta > x_{(1)}$, in which case the likelihood drops to $0$ because it is impossible for $\theta$ to exceed the minimum observed value.  Consequently, the likelihood is maximized for a choice of $\theta$ that is as large as we can make it, which in this case is $$\hat \theta = x_{(1)}.$$

---

As for the consistency of $\hat \theta$, we again start from intuition:  it stands to reason that if $X_i$ are uniformly distributed on $[\theta, 1]$, that the more observations you take, the more likely that the sample minimum will tend toward $\theta$.  In fact, you can write this probability explicitly by computing the CDF of $X_{(1)}$:  $$F_{X_{(1)}}(x) = 1 - \Pr[X_{(1)} > x] = 1 - \Pr\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^n X_i > x \right] = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i > x] = 1 - \left(\frac{1-x}{1-\theta}\right)^n.$$  This implies that for any $0 < \epsilon < 1-\theta$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[X_{(1)} > \epsilon + \theta] = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1 - \epsilon - \theta}{1 - \theta}\right)^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{1-\theta}\right)^n = 0.$$

Comment: Ok, this is fantastic. I get it. But now that I now that $\hat{\theta}$ is $\min{\{X_i\}}$ or $x_{(1)}$ as you wrote. How can I know if it is a consistent estimator? Computing MSE is not saving me this time, or is it?

Comment: @Owl235 consistency means that the probability that your estimator is away from the the true parameter tends to zero asymptotically; and this is what heropup shows.