# What is the log-likelihood function and MLE in uniform distribution $U[\theta,5]$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, uniform-distribution, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

For uniform distribution $U[\theta,5]$ with sample size $n$,

Likelihood function is:
$$L(y;\theta) = (5-\theta)^{(-n)}$$
Log-likelihood function is:
$$\log(L(y;\theta)) = -n.\log(5-\theta)$$
For MLE take the derivative of log-likelihood with respect to $\theta$:
$$(\log(L(y;θ)))' = +n/(5-\theta)$$
$$θ = y(\min)$$
ymin is the minimum of the sample when ordered.In this case y(min)=1.9
Is this correct or am I making a mistake somewhere?Can you point out the mistakes and give an answer of the right form?

Comment: how is $\log (5-\theta)^{(-n)} =  -n\log (3.5-\theta)$ ?

Comment: What are the bounds on $\theta$?  What is $c(y)$ and why does it vanish under taking logarithms?  You have taken some derivative but have not specified with respect to which of the several variables.  Why do you have the wrong sign on your derivative?  What is $min$?  What is your list of critical points?  Why have you not checked the endpoints for maximization?

Comment: @EricTowers bounds on θ is not given in the question. The other questions as much as I can I answer I edited and added to the question. Can you write what is missing as an answer? Also,I added sample list.

Comment: No derivatives necessary here; see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259442/321264 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Y$ is drawn from a uniform distribution  on the interval $[\theta, 5]$ (where, *a priori*, $ \theta \leq 5$).  Then the likelihood of $Y$ given $\theta$ is
$$  L(Y; \theta) = \frac{1}{5-\theta}  \text{.}  $$
Now let $y$ be a sample of $n$ realizations of $Y$, $y = (y_1, \dots, y_n)$.  Note that, necessarily, $\theta \leq y_i$ for all $i$, so let $m$ be the minimum of the $y_i$.  The likelihood of $y$ given $\theta$ is
$$  L(y; \theta) = \begin{cases}
c_y \prod_{i=1}^n L(Y;\theta)  ,& \theta \leq m  \\
0  ,&  m < \theta
\end{cases} \text{,}  $$
where $c_y > 0$ is a normalization constant.  Then
$$  L(y; \theta) = \begin{cases}
c_y \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^n  ,& \theta \leq m  \\
0  ,&  m < \theta
\end{cases}
  \text{.}  $$
We wish to maximize the likelihood with respect to $\theta$.  It is traditional to take logarithms as a computational aid, however
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} \ln L(y; \theta) 
    = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} \ln \left( \begin{cases}
c_y \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^n  ,& \theta \leq m  \\
0  ,&  m < \theta
\end{cases} \right)  $$ has an undefined second piece when taking logarithms, so we do not.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} L(y;\theta)
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} \left( \begin{cases}  
c_y \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^n  ,& \theta \leq m  \\
0  ,&  m < \theta
\end{cases} \right)  \\
    &= \begin{cases}  
c_y n \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^{n+1}  ,& \theta < m  \\
\text{undefined}  ,& \theta = m  \\
0  ,&  m < \theta
\end{cases} \text{,}
\end{align*}
where the derivative is undefined at $\theta = m$ because the function is not continuous there.  Since we are maximizing, we want [critical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)).  Since no value of $\theta$ makes $c_y n \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^{n+1} = 0$ or be undefined, we have found that $(-\infty, m]$ is the set of critical points.  Evaluating $L(y;\theta)$ on the set of critical points, we discover we are always using the first piece of that function, so we study $c_y \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^n$ on $(-\infty, m]$.  We know 
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} c_y \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^n = c_y n \left(\frac{1}{5-\theta}\right)^{n+1}  $$
on $(-\infty, m)$.  Since $c_y > 0$, $n > 0$, and $\theta \leq 5$, this is either a positive number or $y_i = 5$ for all $i$.  If it is a positive number and since $L(y;\theta)$ is continuous on $(-\infty, m]$, the maximum occurs at $\theta = m$.  If $y_i = 5$ for all $i$, then $L(y; \theta)$ is only nonzero at $\theta = m$, where it is positive.  In either case, the maximum occurs at $\theta = m$.

Comment: in my case Maximum likelihood estimate of θ  would be 5?Why didn't we take the derivative of the log-likelihood but the derivative of the likelihood?You wrote derivative of logarithm but then didn't take it? I might be confused

Comment: @moll : The maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ is only $5$ if $m = 5$, which means all the $y_i$ are $5$, which does not happen in your example $y$.  We explain why we do not pretend to take logarithms of zero in the Answer.  The logarithm function is monotonically increasing, so the location of the maximum of the log-likelihood is the same as the location of the maximum of the likelihood.

Comment: But what is log-likelihood then? Is it like written in the question?

Comment: The log-likelihood has domain $(-\infty, m]$ and value $\ln (c_y) - n \ln (5-\theta)$.  Why are you having so much trouble with this one computation?

Comment: thank you for taking your time to reply,I know I ask about trivial stuff but I'm really trying to learn and I am lacking some knowledge in maths :/